# Number of counts of ajax php button click counter doesn't show

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here is my code:

1/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function getXMLHttp()
{
  var xmlHttp
  try
  {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    try
    {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      try
      {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        alert("AJAX not supported.")
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return xmlHttp;
}

function MakeRequest()
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", "count.php", true); 
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

 function HandleResponse(response)
{
  document.getElementById('ResponseDiv').innerHTML = response;
}
    </script>
    <input type='button' onclick='MakeRequest();' value='Button'/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id='ResponseDiv'>
        Count
    </div>
</body>
```

count.php:

```
<?php

$fp = false;
// Open file for reading, then writing
while ( ($fp=fopen('clicks.txt','r+'))===false ) {
    usleep(250000); // Delay 1/4 second
}
// Obtain lock
while ( !flock($fp, LOCK_EX) ) {    
    usleep(250000); // Delay 1/4 second
}
// Read Clicks
$clicks = trim(fread($fp,1024));
// Add click
$clicks++;
// Empty file
ftruncate($fp,0);
// Write clicks
fwrite($fp, $clicks);
// Release Lock
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
// Release handle
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Here is how it functions: I click the button, the AJAX function calls the php that increments the number of clicks then saves it in the txt file. The HandleResponse function is supposed to let me show to the user the number of counts.

I checked the txt file and the number of clicks is tracked. But it never shows in the ResponseDiv. I mean that nothing is shown when the number of clicks should be shown.
What is the problem here ?

Comment: `if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){ HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText); }else{ alert(xmlHttp.readyState); }` make this change, and what does the alert say?

Comment: you are never echoing out `$clicks` just add `echo $clicks;` at the bottom of your script.

Comment: It's better to organize the question like this:
*1*: Description of the problem.
*2*: An explanation of it, with code samples.
*3*: Your last paragraph

Comment: The alert says 1 then 2 then 3 and then actually shows value correctly incremented. But how to show value without an alert saying 1,2,3 ?

Comment: I found the solution. I just added: {if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){ HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText); }else{ HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just added: {if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){ HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText); }else{ HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText); }